# How can i create two different form controls and the merge them in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to add multiple questions(left and right) based on dropdown selection either input box or multiple choice question, but i have two section left and right ,when i select input box from dropdown both sides input box will show (left and right) same way when i select dropdown from dropdown both sides input with option will show.

But on the left and right both the question are different both question will have different id's will create on backend. so i am not able to send question from left and right, like i am not able to differentiate employee ans user added question because both will add question at same time, how can i send `user_type` based on the user who added the question.

Please suggest something,any help would be highly appreciated.
the structure that i need to send to create question on backend:

```js
"questions": [
  {
    "id": null,
    "question": "test",
    "type_of_ques": "comment",
    "ques_user_type": "user",
    "placement": 1,
    "choices": [
      {
        "id": null,
        "choice": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": null,
    "question": "test11",
    "type_of_ques": "dropdown",
    "ques_user_type": "emp",
    "placement": 1,
    "choices": [
      {
        "id": null,
        "choice": "2"
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-fields-cku1ue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Attaching screenshot of UI:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, you can create separate form controls and then merge them using a FormGroup or a FormArray. Take a look below sample piece:

1. Create Individual Form Controls:

First, create your individual form controls using Angular's FormControl class. These will represent the separate parts of your form.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input formControlName="control1" />
      <input formControlName="control2" />
    </form>
  `
})
export class YourComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      control1: ['', Validators.required],
      control2: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
}
```

2. Merge Controls using FormGroup:

You can use a FormGroup to group these controls together.

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  mergedGroup: this.fb.group({
    control1: ['', Validators.required],
    control2: ['', Validators.required],
  })
});
```

Then, in your template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formGroupName="mergedGroup">
    <input formControlName="control1" />
    <input formControlName="control2" />
  </div>
</form>
```

3. Merge Controls using FormArray:

If you want to dynamically manage a list of controls, you can use a FormArray.

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  mergedArray: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
    this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
  ])
});
```

In your template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="mergedArray">
    <div *ngFor="let control of mergedArray.controls; let i = index">
      <input [formControl]="control" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

You can dynamically add or remove controls from the FormArray using functions like push and removeAt.

Remember to import the necessary modules (FormGroup, FormArray, etc.) from @angular/forms.

This way, you can create separate form controls and then merge them using either a FormGroup or a FormArray based on your specific requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you please take a look into the stackblitz code, in case of comment and multiple choice type question we will have whole different object for both along with other fields as well, that's i am confused how can i make formarray for left and right part